# Stuck trying to sum this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I actually got this question from a book - TMH. Here is the question:

> Prove that $\cot^2 \frac{\pi}{2n+1}\cdot \cot^2 \frac{\pi}{2n+1}\cdot \ldots \cdot \cot^2 \frac{\pi}{2n+1}$ are the roots of the equation
> $$
> x^n - \frac{\binom{2n+1}{3}}{\binom{2n+1}{1}} x^{n-1} +\frac{\binom{2n+1}{5}}{\binom{2n+1}{1}}x^{n-2}-\cdots = 0,
> $$and hence show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n} r^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

I noticed the following, but couldn't solve later.
$$
\cot ^{2} \frac{\pi}{2 n+1}=\tan ^{2} \frac{n \pi}{2 n+1}
$$

Comment: Please use the image icon at the top of the editing box to upload your image into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may know the following formula that you will find for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) in paragraph "Sine, cosine, tangent of multiple angles"

$$\displaystyle \tan(n\theta )=\frac {\sum _{k{\text{ odd}=2q+1}}(-1)^{q}{n \choose k}(\tan\theta) ^{2q+1}}{\sum _{k{\text{ even}=2q}}(-1)^{q}{n \choose k}(\tan\theta)^{2q} }\tag{1}$$

Let us take $2n+1$ instead of $n$ in (1) :

$$\displaystyle \tan((2n+1)\theta )=\frac {\sum _{q=0}^n(-1)^{q}{2n+1 \choose 2q+1}(\tan\theta) ^{2q+1}}{\sum _{q=0}^{n}(-1)^{q}{2n+1 \choose 2q}(\tan\theta)^{2q} }\tag{2}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\tan((2n+1)\theta)=0 \ \ \iff \ \ \sum _{q=0}^n (-1)^{q}{2n+1 \choose 2q+1}x^q = 0\ \ \text{with} \ \ x:=\tan(\theta)^2\tag{3}$$

Two remarks :

1) The second equation in (3) is exactly your equation (multiplied by the common denominator) ?

2) This equation has been simplified by $x$ assumed $\ne 0$.

The first equation in (3) is equivalent to :

$$(2n+1) \theta=k\dfrac{\pi}{2} \ \ \text{for any integer} \ k \tag{4}$$

Therefore, $\theta$ can take the values :

$$\theta=\dfrac{k}{2n+1}\dfrac{\pi}{2}\tag{5}$$

Plugging (5) into relationship $x=(\tan\theta)^2$, we get

$$x=\tan(\dfrac{k}{2n+1}\dfrac{\pi}{2})^2=(\cot(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{k}{2n+1}\dfrac{\pi}{2}))^2=(\cot(\dfrac{2n+1-k}{2n+1}\dfrac{\pi}{2}))^2$$

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

With $\alpha:=\frac{\pi}{2n+1}$ De Moivre gives $(\cos\alpha+i \sin\alpha)^{2n+1}=-1$. Expand the left hand side by the binomial theorem, and take the imaginary part. Divide by the highest power of $\sin\alpha$ occurring and you are done.